# Solving a simple system of equations through matrix operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm having trouble with some basic linear algebra. My best searching doesn't exactly come up with the solution I'm looking for. My problem is as follows.

$$
    \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}=A
    \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
    ,~~\text{and}~~
    \begin{bmatrix} y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}=B
    \begin{bmatrix} x_3 \\ x_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $y_1$ and $x_2$ are known. I see that I can rewrite the systems of equations as

$$
    \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}=A'
    \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ x_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
    ~\text{where}~A'= \frac{1}{a_{11}}
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  -a_{12}\\ b_{21} & \det{A}\\ \end{bmatrix}
\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
and similarly
$$
    \begin{bmatrix} x_3 \\ y_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}=B'
    \begin{bmatrix} y_2 \\ x_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
    ~\text{where}~B'= \frac{1}{b_{11}}
    \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  -b_{12}\\ b_{21} & \det{B}\\ \end{bmatrix}
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$

This lets me solve by evaluating \ref{eq1} then plug $y_2$ into \ref{eq2}. However, I'd like to avoid the "plugging" in part. How can I arrive at that solution through matrix operations?

In other words, how do I get to something like this
$$
    \begin{bmatrix} x_3 \\ y_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}=C
    \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ x_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks!